# Transformation to Arc Length Coordinates

Tags: numerical-methods, parametrization

I am having trouble understanding some steps in this procedure:

Arc length $l(p)$ of ${\vec{X}(q)|q \in [a,p]}$ is:
$$l(p) = \int_{a}^{p} \sqrt{X'(p)^2 +Y'(p)^2}dq$$

Given s in $[0,1]$, find p such that $\vec{X(p)} = \vec{x(s)}$ amounts to solving the nonlinear scalar equation 
$$f(p) = l(p) - s l(b) = 0 (1)$$

by using Newton's method.

Where does equation (1) come from and why do we have to find such a $q$

Comment: It appears there are important typos in the question as stated. Context suggests the question should read as follows: Arc length $l(p)$ of ${\vec{X}(q)\mid q \in [a,p]}$ is:
$$
l(p) = \int_{a}^{p} \sqrt{X'(q)^2 +Y'(q)^2}\, dq.
$$

Given $s$ in $[0, 1]$, finding $p$ such that $l(p) = l(b)s$ amounts to solving the nonlinear scalar equation 
$$
f(p) = l(p) - l(b)s = 0
\tag{1}
$$ 
by using Newton's method. (If this is correct, the answer is immediately apparent.)

Comment: Yes I think it is correct. I am sorry to say it is not apparent to me. Can you explain? Why do we multiply $l(b)$ with $s$ and why does it have to be equal to $l(p)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\Reals}{\mathbf{R}}$Let $X:[a, b] \to \Reals^{n}$ be a piecewise-$C^{1}$ path,
$$
\ell(b) = \int_{a}^{b} \|X'(q)\|\, dq
$$
the arc length of $X$. The goal is reparametrize $X$ using $s:[0, 1] \to [a, b]$ so that $x(t) = (X \circ s)(t)$ has constant speed $\|x'(t)\| = \ell(b)$. In other words, given a real number $s$ with $0 \leq s \leq 1$, the goal is to find the real number $p$ with $a \leq p \leq b$ such that
$$
\ell(b) s = \int_{0}^{s} \|x'(t)\|\, dt
  = \int_{a}^{p} \|X'(q)\|\, dq
  = \ell(p).
$$
Rearranging, $f(p) := \ell(p) - \ell(b) s = 0$.

Comment: I am having a hard time understanding. Is there anywhere I can read about this? I can't seem to find anything when googling. Thanks.

Comment: It may help to consider an example, such as the parabola $X(q) = (q, q^{2})$ for $a \leq q \leq b$. The arc length function$$\ell(p) = \frac{1}{4}\left[2p\sqrt{1 + 4p^{2}} - 2a\sqrt{1 + 4a^{2}} + \ln\left\lvert\frac{2p + \sqrt{1 + 4p^{2}}}{2a + \sqrt{1 + 4a^{2}}}\right\rvert\right]$$ can be computed explicitly, but $\ell$ is impossible to invert "in closed form". Nonetheless, $\ell^{-1}:[0, \ell] \to [a, b]$ is a well-defined function, whose values at selected points can be computed numerically, using Newton's method.

Comment: Could you please explain the what $x(t)$ is?

Comment: A path is not a set of points, but _a specific way of tracing a set of points_. The path $x$ is the specific way of tracing the point set $X([a, b])$ at constant speed so that $x(0) = X(a)$ and $x(1) = X(b)$.